# storing listview displaying position in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I have created an android list view that allows users to rearrange the position of each item on it. however, I can't figure out how can I have the 'changed' position stored in the database in the best and most efficient way such that I will be able to retrieve a cursor from the database by using a sort by displaying id function?

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Currently, what I am thinking of is to store the item position in the database as the last item position once it is created and after which when it is changed, i will change the position of the selected item in the database and run a loop to change every other items that is below it, to have an increment of 1.

does this logic make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column in the database named ordinal (type integer), to store the order in which you want the item to appear in the list. When the user re-arranges the list, change the ordinal accordingly.

EDIT:

After reading your update, I do not think that will work because what if the user changes the position of something below the one you update?

Why not just update the position of every item according to the position in their ListView?

So one of your database methods would be:

```
public boolean updateOrdinal(int itemId, int ordinal)

{

    ContentValues c = new ContentValues();


    c.put("ordinal", ordinal);


    return db.update("TableName", c, kID + "=" + itemId, null) > 0;

}
```

This would be called after the user "saves" the list. Of course a loop would have to call this for each item.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i do have a column indicating the position of it's position. i have updated my question, maybe you can have a look at it.

Comment: i don't have much code for the database movement yet. i am still thinking of the appropriate way of doing it.but i do have a listener which will supply me of the positions.

Comment: "After reading your update, I do not think that will work because what if the user changes the position of something below the one you update?" - when the user changes the position of something below, would the item below be the new selected item and run the cycle again?

Comment: because I was thinking if running so many database calls to update every single item position will be necessary, and if there was any better way of working things out, along the line of an java.util.arraylist style which i can move the position of the item easily.

Comment: You would then be dealing with two versions of the data (one in DB and one in an arraylist). Overall, with the speed of phones today, this shouldn't be too bad unless your talking about a list of thousands or hundreds of thousands of items. Then you could put it in its own thread. But I doubt ANY user would want to order a list of anything more than maybe 50-100 items :).

Comment: but does arraylist lalso runs a loop to append every item position if i were to input a value at a specific position like items.add(2, "foo"); - if the arraylist happens to have a size() of 10.

Comment: Are you asking if the user inserts a NEW value into the list what will happen? You would have to check in your loop if the items exists in the database, and insert if it doesn't.

Comment: i was asking about the logic behind the movements of the arraylist. whether if it also run loops to amend the position of items in it (specifically those below the input index), if i were to input a item in the middle of the list. because i felt that the arraylist concept would be a more preferable solution.